# $routeProvider does not route on production server, but works on local machine

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to use Angular.js $routeProvider for my prototype app, it does work fine on my local machine, but fails on production environment. There are nor errors printed on console neither any xhr request sent to get **/partials/signup.php** template

```
window.$APP         = angular.module('ccnApp', ["ngRoute", "ccnControllers", "ccnServices"]);
window.$SERVICES    = angular.module('ccnServices', ['ngResource']);
window.$CONTROLLERS = angular.module("ccnControllers", ["angularFileUpload"]);

/**
 * Routes
 */
$APP.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
        when('/profile', {
            controller: 'ProfileController',
            templateUrl: THEME_URL + 'partials/profile.html'
        }).when('/profile/:profileId', {
            controller: 'ExternalProfileController',
            templateUrl: THEME_URL + 'partials/external-profile.html'
        }).when('/vault', {
            controller: 'VaultController',
            templateUrl: THEME_URL + 'partials/vault.html'
        }).when('/network', {
            controller: 'NetworkController',
            templateUrl: THEME_URL + 'partials/network.html'
        }).when('/signup', {
            controller: 'SignupController',
            templateUrl: THEME_URL + 'partials/signup.php'
        }).when('/login', {
            controller: 'LoginController'
        }).when('/payment', {
            templateUrl: THEME_URL + 'partials/payment.php'
        }).when('/:page', {
            templateUrl: function(parameters) {
                document.location.href = "/" + parameters.page
            }
        });

    $locationProvider
        .html5Mode(true)
        .hashPrefix('!');
}]);
```

Here is the app url *http://ccn.metalabs.io/signup/*

Here is direct link to js code

http://ccn.metalabs.io/wp-content/themes/criticalcontactsnetwork/js/app.js

Could it be because a self signed SSL is used?

Thank you

**Update 1: Here is the thing, I'm using vagrant to manage my dev environment, and when I tried to access my app via vagrant public URL $routeProvider suddenly worked. I think it has something to do with self-signed SSL certificate or some kind of browser policy**

**Update 2: Just disabled SSL, didn't helped. Weird, it works via vagrant shared URL, but does not work on my subdomain.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was the problem. When I transferred wordpress database from dev to production **Page Template** option reset back to **Default Template**, so I didn't even had *ng-view* in html.